# What physics engine support force fields and bodies represented as points?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

I need a game engine that supports force fields in 2d or 3d, but suitable for 2d calculations, like bullet.

Each body I want to simulate is represented as a set of points. Each point has positive mass and can accept force. Force field is updated every tick.
Engine should accept force applied to every point and return point speed values and coordinates.
Each body made of particles should move as a whole thing in result, relative position of particles must persist, hence this is a rigid body.
If engine does not support setting body as a set of points it should allow setting density function, or some other means to let have non-uniform density.

Is there any that can do that, preferably cross-platform.

Comment: Sounds like a particle-engine to me?

Comment: not exactly, particles must form rigid bodies.

Comment: So your bodies must be able to interact despite being points? Or do you (falsely, I think) assume that particle engine particles are rigid bodies? Lastly, it seems your question is ambiguous: is each body a single point or does each body consist of a set of points? Please clarify.

Comment: @Eric each body consists of points in my system, I thought it is clearly stated. And I'd like to simulate this body made of points movement under action of the force field.

Comment: "set of points" is ambiguous, it should be "a set of points" or "sets of points". It was also not clear whether you were referring to all the bodies or a single body. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sorry for that, English is not my native language, still struggling with article usage.

Comment: The force field is not actually part of the physics engine. Each frame the force from the force field is applied to the physics engine, but the actual field is not part of the physics engine, so you will hardly find it in a physics engine. But the force field is pretty simple, it is just a function that takes a position and returns a force vector, you just need to implement it. An easy one is a sphere, in the center the force is strong, outside less, you can use the [inverse square law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/isq.html) for starters.

Comment: Pass that force simply to any physics engine that you like, bullet will do the job too. How many points are we talking about?

Comment: In case you have a lot of bodies forming a gas/cloud/fluid, you might want to look into [bullet's soft bidy simulation paragraph 10](http://www.bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf)

Comment: @MaikSemder I have a force field, I need to apply it to rigid body. point count is 100-1000 points per body. Just applying central force would not work.

Comment: Each physics engine has such functions, for instance bullets [btRigidBody::applyForce(const btVector3& force, const btVector3& rel_pos)](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/btRigidBody_8h_source.html#l00304) and [btSoftBody::addForce (const btVector3 &force, int node)](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtSoftBody.html#afdfb3e29c73cb1a67a0d006eb1e1824d)

Comment: @MaikSemder So in this case I will have to represent my body as a shape, not as a set of points? is it correct? Does bullet allow such body to have non-uniform density? my points can have different mass.

Comment: That depends. A) Are the points fixed relative to each other (rigid)? Or is it B) a soft body, the points move relative to each other, they are connected with constraints/springs? Is it A) or B)?

Comment: "Does bullet allow such body to have non-uniform density" yes

Comment: @MaikSemder Rigid body, adding thst to the post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6963/discussion-between-q-b-and-maik-semder)

Comment: it does not look like non-uniform density can be set for the rigid body, at least not straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, each physics engine will do it, so will Bullet. You can use [btCompoundShape](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCompoundShape.html#_details) to create a rigid body from multiple "sub"-bodies, each with its own mass.